# Как сверстать блок со слайдером, который выходит из своего контейнера?

Tags: css, css3

Коллеги, добрый день.
Прошу вас помочь мне найти решение или укажите где искать

Есть блок с центрированным контейнером.
У него есть 2 потомка по 50%
Во втором потомке есть элемент (тут слайдер), который ВЫХОДИТ за пределы контейнера.

КРАСНОЕ - контейнер.
ЗЕЛЕНОЕ - блок, который из него вылазит

Структура такова

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="slider"></div>
<div>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _"У него есть 2 потомка"_ У блока с контейнером или у контейнера? Там же у Вас наверняка и bootstrap и jQueryUI, плюс сам слайдер и ваши стили - как же без кода решать такую задачу? Ну и не понятно, что должно получится, ибо из вопроса - только знак вопроса.

Comment: Нет ни Бутстрапа, ни UI. Есть ручная сетка и Swiper. Выправила вопрос.

Comment: да, что ж такое?.. Вопрос то в чём? Просто сами для себя прочитайте. Согласитесь, что двояко. Нужно, чтобы вылазил или нужно, чтобы обрезался/скрывался? За нашим диалогом следит десяток человек, а я один Вас пытаю, дабы добиться внятной цели.

Comment: Вылазил. Я написала об этом. Зеленый блок выходит ЗА ПРЕДЕЛЫ красного и обрезается ЭКРАНОМ монитора.

Comment: подозреваю я его придумала, опираясь на дизайн.
Тогда как отцентрировать контент?

Comment: Я добавила кусман дизайна. Фигма защищена как-то так, что не показать никому(

Comment: @Polina: контейнер - `display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;` ?

Comment: Простите, но так не работает.

Comment: предположим, вот моя структура. Примените на ней ваши советы.
https://codepen.io/emelyanova/pen/ZEOMBgx

Comment: @Polina: про flex - это был вопрос, а не утверждение. Медиазапросы присутствуют для моб.версии?

Answer (score 2):

Коллеги, на основании ваших рекомендаций и небольшой "медитации" на тему, я построила сетку так как указано ниже.

Я решила ПОЛНОСТЬЮ избавиться от контейнера в этом блоке.

Благодарю @UModeL за терпение и благоразумие!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  background-color: #ff0;
}

.right {
  background-color: #0df;
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

.box {
  border: 4px solid tomato;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, similique!  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="box">FKG Slider HERE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```